# js.get (из php-страници)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Возникла необходимость сделать на пхп странице "скрипт" который будет на присланный запрос отправлять обратно json файл:

```
{"count":/\*любая цифра\*/}
```

Как это реализовать, чтобы пхп еще мог проверять данные? 
js отправляет через `$.ajax`

Comment: Что вы подразумевате под фразой " чтобы пхп еще мог проверять данние" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте вот так:

**JS**

```
$.post('/url/', data ,function(response){
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  switch (response['status']){
      case 1:
      $('#block').html(response['count']);
      break;
      case 0:
      console.log('Произошла ошибка');
      break;
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?

// Получаете данные
switch (gettype($_POST['data'])){
  case string:
  // Делаете действия с данными
      break;
  case object:
  // Тут тоже можно что-то делать
      break;
}
```

Т.е по началу, Вам надо узнать тип даных, перед тем, чтобы проверять.
Валидация типов - всегда хорошая вещь.

Comment: Либо String, либо Object

Comment: @МиколаКікець, я немножко поправил для Вас скрипт BackEnd'а. Заменил ненужное на то, что действительно поможет в Вашей ситуации. А если Вам нужно больше типов - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gettype.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$number = 5;
$res['count'] = $number;
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?